# Drawing arc in QGIS python API

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible to draw an arc(curve) in QGIS using Python if  the following parameters are known?

1. start point of the arc
2. end point  of the arc
3. arc length
4. direction of the arc from start point to end point
5. Radius (of the circle created from the arc)

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: [Creating ARCs in QGIS: The Python Way](http://www.digital-geography.com/creating-arcs-qgis-python-way/)

Comment: I think that, the "arc length" is not the best parameter to describe arc. You sholud consider parameters: start, end, radius and center (of the circle). It can be generate with numpy.

Comment: @dmh126 parameters start, end and radius of the circle are known (center point of circle is unkown). If arc can be generated with those parameters?

Comment: Center can be calculeted with start, end and radius. I'll try to figure this out later and I'll post the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have derived center point of the circle (formed by the arc) and then computed the midpoint of the arc. Having traced the midpoint, I have used "QgsCircularStringV2" class which creates the arc from its start point, mid point and end point. Refer the [code for arc creation here](http://webgeodatavore.com/create-qgis-curve-from-python-api.html)